# VB.NET to ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Is there a way to convert a [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) application to [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) without changing the code?

Answer (score 8):

ASP.NET isn't a language.  It's a web framework, generally using C# or VB as a language.  VB.NET code can be used directly in ASP.NET, no conversion necessary.

Now, converting something like a WinForms UI to a web UI, that's another story.  And, no, there's no direct way to convert them.  They're vastly different technologies and architectures.  Even if you do find something that claims to do the job, it's going to emit a *terrible* web UI.

But all you should need to change is the UI layer.  The same business logic classes, object models, data access, etc. can all work the same.  (Assuming it's not tightly coupled with the UI, of course... in which case you don't have a language/framework problem so much as an application design problem.)

Comment: may be, he means converting from VB.net to C#.

Comment: @just_name: There's nothing in the question, title or tags to suggest that.